calling and passing arguments between two python files
I am using customtkinter textbox for a GUI in file1, and I want to print multiple texts whenever I call the print function in file1 from file2. Sorry, it's a 300+ LOC. I just put some of the codes here for visualization. So if we press the stop button that stop_exec will be called. Here is the latest edit. Sorry for confusing you.
File1:
import customtkinter as ctk
import tkinter as tk

class App(ctk.CTk):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title("dummy")
        self.geometry(f"{800}x{500}")
        self.SM_data = ctk.CTkTextbox(self, corner_radius=0, fg_color="#dee2e6", text_color="#000000",font=("Tahoma",12), border_width=1, border_color="#000000")
        self.SM_data.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        self.stop_button =ctk.CTkButton(self, width=24, height=24, text="X", anchor="right", hover_color="#D20103", fg_color="#E60808", command= self.stop_execution)
        self.stop_button.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=(0,4), sticky="e")

    def print_SM(self, text):
        print(f"Received text: {text}")  #print measure
        self.SM_data.insert(tk.END, text + "\n")

    def stop_execution(self):
        from File2 import stop_exec
        stop_exec() 

if __name__=="__main__":
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()

File2:
from File1 import App

# Create an instance of the App class
app_instance = App()

def stop_exec():
    y = "test print"
    app_instance.print_SM(y)

The output should be printing "test print" in the textbox.
Also why did i get the additional problem after closing the GUI:
invalid command name "3043397009600update"
    while executing
"3043397009600update"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "3043396906432check_dpi_scaling"
    while executing
"3043396906432check_dpi_scaling"
    ("after" script)
invalid command name "3043397009856<lambda>"
    while executing
"3043397009856<lambda>"
    ("after" script)


where is stop_exec being called?

create a secondary class for File 2 which you pass in the already created app instance from __main__ then you can interact with the App class in File2 (that is the same instance and not just creating duplicate instances like you are currently doing)

Show us the exact command you use to run this code.

You create a new instance of App() inside stop_exec() and call its print_SM() which does not insert text into the already created instance inside File1.
Suggest to pass the already created instance to stop_exec() instead:
File2:
def stop_exec(app_instance):
    y = "test print"
    app_instance.print_SM(y)

File1:
...
class App(ctk.CTk):
   ...
   def stop_execution(self):
       from File2 import stop_exec
       stop_exec(self)  # pass App instance to the function


Thank you. This solve the current problem. shout out to Andrew Ryan also. thank you to u both:)
